# Parse update and deletion not working android

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am working with the android apis and as per this I have done exactly the same as instructed. Here is my code

```
Update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
                .getQuery("GameScore");
        query.whereEqualTo("playerName", user.getText().toString());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg1 == null) {
                    if(arg0.size()!=0)
                    {
                    final ParseObject delo = arg0.get(0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "got something : " + arg0.size() + "  " + delo.getObjectId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String objid = delo.getObjectId();
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> newquery = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
                    newquery.getInBackground(objid, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject arg0, ParseException arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(arg1==null)
                            {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            String scor = score.getText().toString();
                            int iscore = Integer.parseInt(scor);  
                            arg0.put("score", iscore);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            arg0.saveInBackground();
                            }else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "nothing to show",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "We got Crashed" + arg0.size(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Nothing changed in the database.

I thought this may be the problem due to permission so i added this:

defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

and still nothing changed so i went very basic and wrote this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("a26WaZg8MJ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject arg0, ParseException arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg1==null){
        arg0.put("playerName", "cheated");
        arg0.saveInBackground();
        System.out.println("Saved");
        }
    }
});
```

and still nothing happens please help me.

also i am facing problem with deleting a single row. so i tried this and that doesn't work as well.

Comment: 1) is the id for the `ParseObject` correct? 2) if `playerName` is a column that has not been created yet, you need to refresh the browser after `saveInBackground()` finishes for the new column to show.

Comment: yes i know that id is correct because i am able to save and fetch information correctly and the id fetched also matches the actual id.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it the permissions are set for individual objects not for the entire class that is why i was not able to write(update) or delete but the one's that i created after adding the ACLpermission code worked perfectly well.